# rdflib.js with RDFa not returning any results

Tags: javascript, node.js

What I use:

- Ubuntu 14.04
- Node.js 0.10.36
- rdflib.js 0.2.0

What I want to achieve:

- Parse a html file with RDFa information
- Print the found RDF triples

What I have in my Node.js script:

```
var rdflib = require('rdflib');
var kb = new rdflib.Formula();

rdflib.parse("http://ceur-ws.org/Vol-1085/", kb, "http://www.example.com/", "application/rdfa");
console.log(kb.statements);
```

The code of rdflib.js calls the third parameter of the 'parse' method 'base', however, I don't know what they mean by that, so I just added dummy URI.
What I get as a result:

```
[]
```

Hence, the there are no statements in the store. I would expect to see here the different triples that are present in the html file. Can anybody see what the problem is?

P.S. Because there is no (recent) documentation on how to use rdflib.js, I might be using the above methods in the wrong way.

Answer (score 0):

The first argument of rdflib.parse takes a string that contains the resource at that URI, it doesn't read the URI. You need to use something like request to read the entity body first. Also the URI http://ceur-ws.org/Vol-1085/ does not seem to return application/rdf+xml.